# Quick Way to Integrate Quadratic Denominators?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a quick way to evaluate

$\int \frac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c}$

$\int \frac{dx}{(ax^2+bx+c)^n}$

without memorizing any inverse sines or tans, or ending up with crazy reduction formulae - preferably with some intuitive reason why we get the answer we get?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions#Integrands_of_the_form_xm_.2F_.28a_x2_.2B_b_x_.2B_c.29n

Answer (score 1):

**Preposition**: No.

*Proof*:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\pi$$

Comment: Perhaps the brevity darkens a bit what I want to say. The function $1/(x^2+1)$ is the simplest of the class what you are asking abount, and the integral over its domain its $\pi$, a constant that has an narrow relation with trigonometric functions. This is not a mathematical  proof, of course, but I think that it illustrates that there are no shortcuts.

Comment: These are *indefinite* integrals

Comment: Indefinite integrals have much more information that definite ones. If a definite integral with no apparent trace of $\pi$ is $\pi$, surely it's because of the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 0):

you can express the quadratic as a product of 2 monomials over $\mathbb{C}$, and then express it as an integral of a sum of the inverse of monomials.  without boundaries on the integrals this is pretty quick.

Comment: $x^2+ax+b=(x+c)(x+d)$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{C}$ then $\int\frac{1}{x^2+ax+b}dx=\int\frac{1}{(x+c)(x+d)}dx$ which can be broken apart by partial fractions.

Comment: This requires computing the *complex* numerators $A$ and $B$ s.t. $A/(x+c)+B/(x+d)=1/(x^2+ax+b)$, an easy but somewhat long and tedious task.

Comment: $A=-B$ & $B=\frac{1}{c-d}$ So, a little work, but nothing too much if you dont mind working in complex numbers.  In my mind the more arduous task is evaluating the integral as logarithms and then simplifying that, but again, this depends on comfort with complex numbers.

Comment: What about when this is raised to the n'th power, and what about getting the result you get when you do it with real numbers only (for both cases)?

Comment: basically what @lab bhattacharjee wrote above.  but the computations are not pretty.